# How do I change my code to use arrays?

Tags: python, arrays

This is my code so far. I can get my code to prompt the user to input 4 test scores. I have made it so it asks "Enter the score for test number N:"

My problem lies in being able to extract the input values from what the user would input. My end goal is to be able to drop the lowest test grade and calculate an average with the remaining scores. Input data used would be 99, 99, 99 and 77.

I have an example that takes the min from a variable that is assigned X numbers but not from when you would get it from a user input.

```
def main():
    scores = getNumbers()

def getNumbers():
    testCountIs = 0
    testNum = 4
    totalScore = 0

    for test in range(1, testNum+1):
        print('Enter the score for test number', int(testCountIs+1), end='')
        testScores = int(input(': '))
        testCountIs += 1

main()
```

Edit2: below is the code that works for this program.

```
    def main():
        scores = getNumbers()
        print("The average with the lowest score dropped is: ",float(sum(scores))/len(scores))

    def getNumbers():
        scores=[]
        for testNum in range(4):
           print('Enter the score for test number',int(testNum+1),end='')
           scores.append(int(input(': ')))
        scores=[score for score in scores if min(scores)!=score]
        return scores

    main()
```

Comment: This should be a good starting point: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm

Comment: I think you mean lists... While python has arrays, `[]` is called a list

Comment: It makes more sense for your loop to start from zero, and assign `test_score[test]`. You don't really need the count, as that basically just duplicates the loop index.

Comment: You are correct, my teacher uses the terms interchangeably.

Comment: Has your teacher, or textbook of you have one, not taught them, then? All you need is to get a list, and `append` to it within the loop. You'll also want to return it because currently, your `getNumbers()` function returns and assigns `None` to `scores`

Comment: She taught us only by having the numbers assigned to a variable. Never an instance where we would need to get the values out from inputted data. The one example that has input data doesn't have the need for the test number to change. That's where I initially ran into problems as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
def getNumbers():
   scores=[]
   for testNum in range(4):
       print('Enter the score for test number %d'%(testNum+1)),
       scores.append(input(': '))
   scores=[score for score in scores if min(scores)!=score]
   return scores

scores= getNumbers()
average= float(sum(scores))/len(scores)
print average
```

**Edit** For python3

```
def getNumbers():
    scores=[]
    for testNum in range(4):
       print('Enter the score for test number',int(testNum+1),end='')
       scores.append(int(input(': ')))
    scores=[score for score in scores if min(scores)!=score]
    return scores

scores= getNumbers()
print(float(sum(scores))/len(scores))
```

Comment: Why do you need to split on a colon? I think the question just wanted to be prompted for `testNum` values, not input `1:2:3`

Comment: Answer says, "assuming that the input scores are separated by :"

Comment: I understood that, but the `testNum` values was  my point. It doesn't appear that a single line of input is what is wanted

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by space separated. My program will need to prompt the user 4 times to enter their test scores separately.

Comment: Added code for that as well. Use the code in edit2, which is what, I guess, you want.

Comment: When I try your code it does not repeat 4 times. Just the one time.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. mistakenly I put the return statement within the loop. Edited it, and it works fine now.

Comment: So far your code and my original do the same except yours is formatted like this
"Enter the score for test number N"
":"

Comment: ** sorry I pressed enter before finishing my thoughts the "Enter the score for test number N" is on a different line than the ":"

Comment: Did you run the code in Edit2? It returns the list/array of scores except the minimum score which your code doesn't. Please, copy the latest edited code and run it.

Comment: This is the output I get with yours: http://i.imgur.com/26AwJP4.png
this is the output I get with my code: http://i.imgur.com/wYuVBsC.png

Comment: Look, this is what I get when I run the code given above,  http://imgur.com/a/Aio5k

Comment: I am using Python 3.5.2 if that makes any difference. I typed you code like in your image and I got a "EOL while scanning literal string" error message. It highlights the line right before the scores.append.

Comment: @Alina That's because of the training comma on the previous line

Comment: @Alina: I used Python2.7.6 interpreter to run the above code. Now, added code which can be interpreted by Python3.5.2. So that should run on your system now.

Comment: Yes, This is SO close. Okay one last thing, it repeat the program in a loop is there any way to end it after it outputs 99 as the average?

Comment: What do you mean by "It repeats"? call to defNumbers() actually prompts user to enter 4 numbers and returns an array/list of 3 numbers, excluding the smallest score, and finally prints the average of the remaining numbers. Please specify your problem a bit clearly.

Comment: It completes the average with the remaining 3 scores and at the same time the line of output after starts the prompt again to enter the test score for test number 1

Comment: I've fixed it and will be editing my code with the answer! Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Your code was close. Just need to define a list, append to it, then return it

```
scores = [] 
for test in range(testNum):
    print('Enter the score for test number', int(test + 1), end='')
    score =  int(input(': ')
    scores.append(score) 
return scores
```

You should calculate the minimum, drop it, and find the average outside of this function

Comment: how do I append a list that will be inputted?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You obtain the input before you append. I just did both together in one line. But I've edited to clarify that